# Casting COALESCE to INT in Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, casting

I currently have a stored procedure which returns data and displayed in my report viewer but my issue is that i check to see if students attended to class or not and i have

```
COALESCE(A.Attended, 0)AS Attended
```

This returns 1 if they attended and 0 if not - in my report it only shows 1 or 0 even though they could have attended more than once. How can i cast this to an int to get the right total.

thanks

WHOLE QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    P.PartyId,
    COUNT(COALESCE(A.Attended, 0))AS Attended,
    COUNT(DISTINCT H.HearingId) AS Hearings,
    O.OfficeName As OfficeName,
    CO.Name,
    P.FirstName AS FirstName,
    P.LastName AS LastName,
    P.BirthDate AS DOB
FROM Activity A 
INNER JOIN ActivityType AT On A.ActivityTypeId = AT.ActivityTypeId
INNER JOIN ActivityEntry AE ON A.ActivityEntryId = AE.ActivityEntryId
INNER JOIN HearingEntry HE ON CAE.HearingEntryId = HE.HearingEntryId
INNER JOIN Hearing H ON HE.HearingEntryId = H.HearingEntryId
INNER JOIN [Case] C ON H.CaseId = C.CaseId
INNER JOIN CaseOffice CO ON C.CaseId = CO.CaseId AND AE.OfficeId = CO.OfficeId
INNER JOIN Office O ON CO.OfficeId = O.OfficeId
INNER JOIN Attended A ON H.HearingId = A.HearingId
INNER JOIN Party P ON A.PartyId = P.PartyId
WHERE HP.PartyId = P.PartyId AND AE.OfficeId = @OfficeId AND(H.HearingDate >= @BeginDate AND (H.HearingDate <= @EndDate OR H.HearingDate IS NULL)) AND HE.HearingEntryId = CAE.HearingEntryId
GROUP BY P.PartyId, A.Attended, O.OfficeName,CO.Name,P.FirstName, P.LastName,P.BirthDate
```

Comment: Please post your whole query. You will need some sort of aggregate query.

Comment: This sounds like an error in the query not COALESCE or casting. What is the full query? Have you verified that the acutal A.Attended is not 1?

Comment: @MartinSmith I went ahead and added the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to SUM by Attended .

```
SELECT 
    P.PartyId,
    (SUM(COALESCE(A.Attended, 0)))AS Attended,
    COUNT(DISTINCT H.HearingId) AS Hearings,
    O.OfficeName As OfficeName,
    CO.Name,
    P.FirstName AS FirstName,
    P.LastName AS LastName,
    P.BirthDate AS DOB
FROM Activity A 
INNER JOIN ActivityType AT On A.ActivityTypeId = AT.ActivityTypeId
INNER JOIN ActivityEntry AE ON A.ActivityEntryId = AE.ActivityEntryId
INNER JOIN HearingEntry HE ON CAE.HearingEntryId = HE.HearingEntryId
INNER JOIN Hearing H ON HE.HearingEntryId = H.HearingEntryId
INNER JOIN [Case] C ON H.CaseId = C.CaseId
INNER JOIN CaseOffice CO ON C.CaseId = CO.CaseId AND AE.OfficeId = CO.OfficeId
INNER JOIN Office O ON CO.OfficeId = O.OfficeId
INNER JOIN Attended A ON H.HearingId = A.HearingId
INNER JOIN Party P ON A.PartyId = P.PartyId
WHERE HP.PartyId = P.PartyId AND AE.OfficeId = @OfficeId AND(H.HearingDate >= @BeginDate AND (H.HearingDate <= @EndDate OR H.HearingDate IS NULL)) AND HE.HearingEntryId = CAE.HearingEntryId
GROUP BY P.PartyId, O.OfficeName,CO.Name,P.FirstName, P.LastName,P.BirthDate
```

Comment: Thanks i think now its looking good but a new issue showed up and maybe some advice on how to resolve it would be great. Now i am getting the number of ATTENDED greater than the HEARINGS. That isn't right because HEARINGS is the total number and from that the ATTENDED number should be equal or less than the HEARINGS possible for a party.

Comment: @Amina that means some of your INNER JOINS are skewing the results. I can't tell you which as I don't know the schema and the data. My advise is that you troubleshoot this by starting with one inner join, run the query and add one more inner join at a time, until you see where the total is getting out of whack.

Comment: thanks a bunch i will go ahead and try that and hopefully that will resolve it. Thanks again...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean that A.Attented is a bit and you want it to be a int, so that you can aggregate later?

You can cast to a bit to an int like this:

```
CAST(A.Attented AS INT)
```

Or in this case:

```
COALESCE(CAST(A.Attended AS INT), 0) AS Attended
```

Comment: +1 But the OP will also need `COALESCE(SUM` not `COUNT(COALESCE`